# Proof that $(3\cdot 2^n-1)$ is not a multiple of $17$ for any value of $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that $3\cdot 2^n-1$ is not a multiple of $17$ for any positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is $n$ such 
$$
3 \cdot 2^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod{17}.
$$
Multiply by 6 on both sides and simplify by $2$ (which is coprime to $17$) to get
$$
2^{n-1} \equiv 3 \pmod{17}.
$$
But
$$
2^{8} = (2^{4})^{2} \equiv (-1)^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{17},
$$
while
$$
3^{8} = (3^{4})^{2} \equiv (-4)^{2} \equiv -1 \pmod{17}.
$$

---

**EDIT** after a suggestion of @fleablood to spell out the ending.

This leads to the contradiction
$$
1 \equiv (2^{8})^{n-1} \equiv (2^{n-1})^{8} \equiv 3^{8} \equiv -1 \pmod{17}.
$$

Comment: I like this proof because it doesn't goes to check all the possible residues modulo $17$ .Good job !

Comment: I'm sure I'm going to be kicking myself, but I don't follow.  Why should $3^8$ equal $2^8$?  It should be equal to $2^{8n - 8}$ (which in turn should be equal to $(2^8)^{n-1} = 1$ but it needs to be spelled out, I think).

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I really don't understand your proof, if you multiply by 6 you should get $9 \cdot 2^{n+1} \equiv 6 \pmod{17}$ and then dividing by 2 should raise $9 \cdot 2^{n} \equiv 3 \pmod{17}$

Comment: @stity He used the fact that $18 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$

Comment: @fleablood, I never claimed that. It's just that if $2^{n-1} \equiv 3 \pmod{17}$, then $1 \equiv (2^{8})^{n-1} \equiv (2^{n-1})^{8} \equiv 3^{8} \equiv -1  \pmod{17}$, a contradiction.

Comment: I realized that must be what you meant as I typed my comment.  But it isn't clear in your proof.  You claim $2^8 = 1$ but $3^8 = -1$ and my only thought is "so what; what does that have to do with $2^{n-1} = 3?"

Comment: @fleablood, ok, will edit with credit, thanks.

Comment: It is a nice proof in that you don't list out all 8 cases.

Comment: There is a typo on the last line : you forgot a minus sign @AndreasCaranti

Comment: @stity fixed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$$2^n \equiv 1,2,4,8,16,15,13,9 \pmod {17}$$
$$3 \cdot 2^n \equiv 3,6,12,7,14,11,5,10 \pmod {17} $$

Answer (score 1):

For $n=4k$, $k \geq 0$ we have that $$2^n \equiv \pm1 \pmod {17} \Rightarrow 3\cdot 2^n-1 \equiv 2,-4 \equiv 2,13 \pmod {17}$$
For $n=4k+1$, $k \geq 0$ we have that $$2^n \equiv \pm2 \pmod {17} \Rightarrow 3\cdot 2^n-1 \equiv 5,-7 \equiv 5,10 \pmod {17}$$
For $n=4k+2$, $k \geq 0$  we have that $$2^n \equiv \pm4 \pmod {17} \Rightarrow 3\cdot 2^n-1 \equiv 11,-13 \equiv 11,4 \pmod {17}$$
For $n=4k+3$, $k \geq 0$  we have that $$2^n \equiv \pm8 \pmod {17} \Rightarrow 3\cdot 2^n-1 \equiv 23,-25 \equiv 6,9 \pmod {17}$$

Hence we can conclude that $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $17$ does not divide $(3\cdot 2^n -1)$.

Comment: $2 \neq -2 \mod 17$

Comment: @NeinDochOah I know but there is no $k$ such that $2 = 17k -2$ or $k'$ such as $2=17k'+15$ as you like

Comment: @stity I have updated my answer. See if you have any objections to this.

Comment: @stity right thats also an issue, I was more concerned with the *proof* that this works for all n.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat $2^8=256 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$ so I still disagree

Comment: Um $2^8 = 1 \mod 17$ not $-1$.  If $2^{4k} = -1$ the $2^{2(4k} = 1$.

Comment: @fleablood I have noticed the flaw. I am correcting it.

Comment: @stity Is it okay now? My edit is finished.

Comment: Your shouldn't do $n = 4k + 1$ as $2^4 \ne 1 \mod 17$.  So $2^{4k +i} = 2^4* 2^{4(k-1) + i} \ne 2^{4(k-1} +i}$.  This'll never work $2^5 \ne 2^9$ and $2^15 \ne 2^19$ etc.

Comment: It loops with 8. But then again thats nowhere shown. At least something like $2^{8+1} = 2^8*2$ and $2^8$ is in the list and $2^1$ is in the list...

Comment: 23 = 5. and those cases are all in your examples so why single them out?  I think it'd be best to do this mod 8. rather than mod 4.  But you could do 4k + 1 = a if k is even and b if k is odd if you think a long list is distracting.

Comment: @fleablood I couldn't understand your last 2 comments. Where is my answer wrong?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat it's ok now, thanks for editing

Comment: @stity Thanks for helping.

Comment: It's okay now.  But you were assuming $2^{4k + i}$ were constant.  They aren't.  As $2^4 = -1$ we know $2^{4k + i} = - 2^{4(k-1) + i$.  So your first proof just didn't work.  It does now.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for your suggestions.. :-)

Comment: "And for the cases n=0,1,2,3 it can be noted that (3⋅2n−1) is equal to 2,5,11,23 respectively, none of whom are divisible by 17."  23 = 5 mod 17.  And why did you include this sentence in at all?  These are cases covered in your claims above with k = 0.

Comment: @fleablood I had included the sentence to make up for an earlier mistake. Now it need not be here any more.I have appropriately corrected my post by deleting those statements..